# Возможно ли выводить поля и игнорировать не нужные?

Tags: php, sql

Добрый день, возможно ли выводить поля с таблицы и игнорирования любой из них? Например,

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Таблица");
```

Выводим все поля, теперь я хочу, чтобы он выводил все поля, кроме тех значений где id = 1 или id = 2 и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM Таблица WHERE id<>1 or id<>2
```

Comment: Кнопочка "Принять ответ" для этого есть :)
Не за что!

Answer (score 1):

Имхо, так красивее, удобнее и понятнее

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id NOT IN(1,2)
```